# Como obter cookie no Web API em um cenário de Forms Authentication em Cross Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Possuo as seguintes aplicações .Net:

1. Aplicação Web com Forms Authentication (Não estou utilizando o
   MVC, utilizo o Backbone.js para fazer chamadas a API REST)
2. Aplicação Web API REST compartilhando o mesmo Forms Authenticaion
   utilizado na aplicação 1.

Estou utilizando o mesmo machineKey em ambos os projetos para que o cookie seja único nos dois. [referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

**A configurações de único cookie em ambas aplicações aparentemente está funcionando (não tenho certeza), porém como faço para obter o cookie na aplicação Web API?**

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o cookie em um controller da WebApi basta utilizar `Request.Headers.GetCookies('nome do cookie')`

Answer (score 0):

Só será possivel isso se ambas as apliações estiverem no mesmo servidor e compartilhando o mesmo diretório virtual.

Qualquer cenário diferente disso, não será possível. Então, se for hospedar em nuvem, já pode descartar.

Se tiver obedecendo os critério acima, basta definir o `PATH` do cookie como `/` e pronto, ambas aplicações irão consumir os mesmo cookies.

Comment: O cenário já está como vc descreveu. O que eu necessito é saber como obter o cookie via código na aplicação Web API.